# Memory leak while using emoticons on CRichEditCtrl

Tags: c++, c, windows, mfc

I'm developing a text editor class (for a chat application) based on `CRichEditCtrl` (MFC) with emoticon support.

After I load the emoticon's bitmap, I use the function `OleCreateStaticFromData` to insert it into  `CRichEditCtrl`. After that I just delete the bitmap object allocated by myself. I can verify (using a `GDIView` utility) that all resources I allocate have been properly released.

This works perfectly: the bitmap (emoticon) is drawn on the `CRichEditCtrl` window and is handled just like a character.

My problem is that I don't know how to deallocate the memory (internal) allocated by `OleCreateStaticFromData` to manage the bitmap (emoticon). The memory allocated for any emoticon used is never released, even if I delete the `CRichEditCtrl` object. I'd like to know how to fix that issue. Is that a MFC's issue or I'm doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`OleCreateStaticFromData` returns a COM pointer which you pass to the Rich Edit control. This COM pointer has had an `AddRef` applied to it, so you must call `Release` once you have passed it to the control, to signify that you no longer will be accessing it directly. The control will also do a `Release` when it is destroyed which should result in the COM object being deleted.

You might also store the returned pointer in a smart pointer class [`_com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [`CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and it will `Release` it automatically.